# C# linechart dynamically databind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, charts

I want to be able to create charts dynamically for this I created the following class with a method called `getChart()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
namespace Henvendelser
{
    class ChartDataCreator
    {
        private Dictionary<String, List<ContactQueue>> dataList;

        public ChartDataCreator() {

        }

        public Chart getChart(String choice) {

            Chart c = new Chart();
            LineSeries ls = new LineSeries();
            ls.IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}";
            ls.DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}";
            ls.ItemsSource =

            new KeyValuePair<int, int>[]{
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(1, 12),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(2, 25),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(3, 5),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(4, 6),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(5, 10),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(6, 4),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(7, 40),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(8, 12),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(9, 25),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(10, 5),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(11, 6),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(12, 10),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(13, 4),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(14, 8),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(15, 9),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(16, 50),
            new KeyValuePair<int,int>(17, 40) };
            c.Series.Add(ls);
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see my code has an error the:

`ls.IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}";
            ls.DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}";`

My question how do you set the independent and dependent binding dynamically. Also please point out if there is something else I'm missing in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, they are looking for Binding Objects so thats what you have to provide it.

```
Chart c = new Chart();
LineSeries ls = new LineSeries();
// For new binding you provide it the string path to your property.
Binding bindInd = new Binding("Key");
Binding bindDep = new Binding("Value");
// then you can set the properties of your binding like so
bindInd.Source = <your source>;
bindDep.Source = <Your Source>;
bindDep.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
bindInd.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
ls.IndependentValueBinding = bindInd;
ls.DependentValueBinding =bindDep;
```

Comment: instead of bindInd.Source = <your source>;
bindDep.Source = <Your Source>;


would i be able to do:    ls.ItemsSource = List<KeyValuePair<String, int>>(); ?

Comment: you can put what ever binding source you want there i was just trying to show that, that is where you would put it.